# How to print out dictation transcript using Wit.ai, Voice SDK and Unreal Engine

Tags: virtual-reality, voice-recognition, unreal-engine5, wit.ai

I'm using UE 5.2 building for VR on the Quest.
I have the Voice SDK installed.
In the docs there is info about installation https://github.com/wit-ai/voicesdk-unreal but no real info on how to use the dictation service that comes with the sdk.

There's no real info re: setting up the blueprints and what nodes to use.

There is an On Partial Transcription event - that does seem to return the transcript but OnPartialTranscription is never getting called.

[nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58fCJ.png)

There is a samples project but there is no information in the dictation blueprint.

I am pretty sure I have the basics set up right (like the wit.ai app) because the Dictation Activated and Dictation Started events/nodes are called.

Need help.